# Laravel Blade component method not rendering in cpanel-server but work in my localhost

Tags: laravel, components, cpanel, laravel-8

I have a component RemoveBook in app/View/Components/RemoveBook and the blade component in resources/views/components/sections/parts/remove-book.blade.php.

all working fine on localhost
but on the server - Cpanel - not rendering

component code

```
public $route;
public $bookid;
/**
 * Create a new component instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($route, $bookid)
{
    $this->route = $route;
    $this->bookid = $bookid;
}

/**
 * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
 */
public function render()
{
    $this->route = Request::is('myBook*') ? 'myBook.destroy' : 'wishList.destroy';
    return view('components.sections.parts.remove-book');
}
```

in view

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => [$route, $bookid], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
<div class="absolute top-0 right-0">
    <button class="w-35-px h-35-px bg-brand-black text-white border hover:opacity-100">
        X
    </button>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and more than 5 components not rendering on the server - all components - but on localhost all working fine

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
composer install
```

then

```
composer update
```

then

```
composer dump-autoload
```

then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not worked on server host and all of the code working except components

Answer (score 0):

just Try

> php artisan view:clear

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Rename component class name, it must start with uppercase letter.

```
class ClassName extends Component{
}
```